# Python Data Extraction from Text File

Tags: python, text-files, extract

The problem is data extraction from a bunch of junk in a text file. For example, first, I need to pull out this particular section from the text file:

%T 525 1:0.00:6425.12 2:0.01:6231.12 3:0.00:3234.51 and goes on for quite long.

Then, I need to specifically pull out the 3rd data from each phrase, that is 6425.12, 6231.12 and 3234.51 and write it to a new text file and then do some other editing on this data.

I was looking into using regular expression for this case. Can anyone show sample code? Should be quite straight forward for an experience programmer.

Comment: How is the string you've posted different from all the other strings in the file?  That is necessary to be able to craft a regex sufficient for picking out that string instead of the next string which may (or may not) look like `%T 526 1:0.00:...`

Comment: Yes, consider using regular expressions. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Regular_Expression

Comment: Ok sorry guys. So far I have been doing a lot of testing and Googling. I managed to pull out that particular section from other junks using startswith and write it into a new textfile. Now the problem is what function to use in Python for such specific data extraction on all the 3rd data in each phrase (6425.12, 6231.12,3234.51,...). I do not have the entire text file with me now. It is in another computer. I can post it tomorrow. But basically, I need help to pull every third data out from each phrase.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `re` to get the numbers...

```
s='%T 525 1:0.00:6425.12 2:0.01:6231.12 3:0.00:3234.51'
columns=s.split()[2:]  #Create a list of all the columns except the first 2.
numbers=[c.split(':')[-1] for c in columns]  #Split each column on ':' and take the last piece.
```

However, we need a little more information about the structure of the file before we can determine how to pick out the string `s` in the first place.

Comment: Elegant and simple. I was complicating matters in my head while the trick was using 2 split and the [] to capture the elements in a string. Enlightening ! I wish I can vote up but I can't. New here. Thanks to all !

Comment: I captured the %T 525 1:0.00:6425.12 2:0.01:6231.12 3:0.00:3234.51 and so on section using startswith and write this section into a new textfile. Convert the new text file into string??????? Other ways to capture this section? Ok I will try provide more info on the original textfile

Comment: @MelvinAng I'm sorry, I don't understand what your last comment is asking.  if `startswith` is good enough, use it -- I doubt you'd get any performance gain from `re`.  As far as writing the numbers into a new text file, you can use the `join` method to convert my list "numbers" into a string.  e.g. `','.join(numbers)` will create a string with ',' between each of the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I'd resort to regex for this, looks pretty simple.

```
with open(...) as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
             if ':' in word:
                  print word.split(':')[2]  # do something with it here
```